# Neither keyboard nor mouse are working

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I have an issue, as the title says. I can't control my computer because neither mouse nor keyboard are working.

When I plugin the device (mouse or keyboard), I got the message

> Device Not Recognized

I have tried a couple of mouses and switched ports, thinking the problem is in the device itself, but however, the message stayed the same.

On my computer I've got the touchscreen feature, but I ain't got no driver installed for it. So the problem still stays:

How to, at least, enable the touchscreen without mouse or keyboard?

Comment: It would help, at the very least to know what kind of computer you have, not to mention the OK, Keyboard and mouse type, etc... At the moment, all we can say is "Have you turned if off and on again?"

Comment: I have "All in One PC" Medion Akoya P9624 model. Yes I tried also pluging out of electricity.  EDIT: I'm having the issue for a longer time now, so I've tried many things.

Comment: @SejoTz Does a memory stick work? If so, you could try a Sandisk U3 drive reformatted to replace the iso with something with an autorun that installs the touchscreen driver.

Comment: It's also possible that _one_ of your USB ports will work fine, and the others won't. It might be a hub chaining issue, in which case I'd hope that the hardware designers would've tried to mitigate the problem.

Comment: @wizzwizz Yes it does. But I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: @SejoTz Yes to memorystick or one port? If a memory stick works… can you use your keyboard when the computer's starting up? Press and hold the power button until it turns off, then mash the F2 key (at the top of the keyboard) until it lets you into the BIOS settings. I've a suspicion that this'll work. If so, it's a Windows driver issue.

Comment: As I mentioned I have "All in One PC" it's made like that to have only 4 usb ports.  2 of them broke and are dead. Only the other two are working and they run everything I plugin exepct mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Memorystick works. But keyboard does not work on windows starting. That is also interesting to me that is not working on a boot up.

Comment: Have you tried other keyboards? And just the keyboard / just the mouse? Sometimes a bad USB device can cause a variety of problems even for the rest of the time the computer is running.  I'll have to go for now, though.

Comment: I only tried different mouses and only one keyboard (Im looking to buy the other kb to try it). Thanks you anyways. I guess I will need to look for some professional tehnical help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to connect a PS/2 mouse and keyboard, if you have access to these.  They are the older style connectors.  Mouse connector is green and keyboard is purple.

I believe a reboot is necessary after connecting PS/2 peripherals before they function properly.

Comment: That would be the solution, but there ain't any ps/2 ports in my motherboard.

Comment: If your computer is connected to a network, you could try RDP from another machine.  This would only work if the PC was previously set up for RDP though.

Comment: Really?  A downvote?  At the very least, he needs to be able to operate the PC to do any kind of troubleshooting, driver updates, etc.

Comment: I never used RDP before and I tried now but could not connect. I guess it's not set up and at this point it can't be.

Comment: @beardedmogul The downvote was probably given because this answer won't work in this case. Given the information in the question, though, it shouldn't have received one imo. You might find the [tour] useful.